# Is it allowed to ask someone to add you on your social network on SO?

Tags: feature-request, contact

How can someone ask his fellow to stay in touch or add him on social networks? Is it allowed to ask this kind of questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How would you ask someone such a specific question? Questions on SO are for everyone to see, so how would you target a specific person?

Comment: @Oded: Please follow me on twitter: http://twitter.com/mattlunn

Comment: If you're in a friendly conversation with somebody in comments, you can ask them to friend you or follow you or whatever. You can also add the info in your profile

Comment: @Matt - Exactly. Or in chat. And I can't flag that comment, as it happens to be on topic ;)

Comment: @Oded Follow him and flag as obsolete 8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could put something in your profile for all to see. However, that would rely on the people you wanted to connect with viewing your profile.

Others have mentioned comments, but these are likely to be removed as noise.

A better way might be to find the person on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and ask them in there.

Looking at the problem from the other end - you could check their profile to see if they've listed any social networks there (I have for example) and you could initiate the contact that way.

Comment: What if he isn't present on Chat?

Comment: @Le3jeb In that case wait until they are. Stack Exchange is not a social network.

Comment: http://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=http://i432.photobucket.com/albums/qq41/waisodim666/4char-forever-alone-guy-high-resolution.png&imgrefurl=http://media.photobucket.com/image/forever%2520alone/waisodim666/4char-forever-alone-guy-high-resolution.png?o%3D7&h=1023&w=882&sz=174&tbnid=UiG1y_kF_XrilM:&tbnh=92&tbnw=79&zoom=1&usg=__I4IjsYYaFtBZKQqgQxxJXD3TZAg=&docid=83zWKpYAFCmmfM&sa=X&ei=D7bRUMHxEKeH0AXo7oFI&ved=0CEIQ9QEwAQ&dur=2788

Comment: @Le3jeb - It's not something I'd want to see added.